# model_pruner failed: Invalid argument: Invalid input graph when run tensorflow c++ API Ubuntu16.04

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

Tensorflow c++ verison:1.13.1
Platform:Ubuntu16.04
tool:eclipse
I have built libtensorflow_cc.so and test it successfully with few examples like loading mnist dataset.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GZJH.png)

The picture above returns right result even though printing some warning.
Recently I try to translate my python code to c++ version and here below is a piece of python code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import  numpy as np
from skimage import io, transform
import cv2
sess = tf.Session()
new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(r'D:\CNN_test_result_sizhuangzao_model\v2_101_ziji_9\model\model.meta')                      new_saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint(r'D:\CNN_test_result_sizhuangzao_model\v2_101_ziji_9\model'))

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
#Here is confusing to me."input:0" and "is_training:0" are two tensors in python
#How does tensorflow c++ put in 2 tensors as the first argument of session->run()?
input_x = graph.get_tensor_by_name("input:0")
is_training_x=graph.get_tensor_by_name("is_training:0")

jpg_path=r"D:\CNN_test_result_sizhuangzao\chaodacesiji1\pos.txt"
file = open(jpg_path)
lines = file.readlines()
num=0
for line in lines: 
    img0 = io.imread(line.strip())
    l=img0.shape
    k=l[0]
    c=l[1]
    num+=1
    print(num)
    if  c/k<5:
        continue
    img = transform.resize(img0, (48,160, 1))
    feed_dict={input_x:np.reshape(img, [-1, 48, 160, 1]),is_training_x:False}
    #And here 'output' is an operation and "output:0" is a tensor in python.How does tensorflow c++ describe them ?
    prob_op = graph.get_operation_by_name('output')
    out_softmax = graph.get_tensor_by_name("output:0")
    img_out_softmax = sess.run(out_softmax,feed_dict)
    prediction_labels = np.argmax(img_out_softmax,1)
```

I have tried tensorflow c++ as the following code 
(This function is changed slightly according to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc)
    '''
    int main()
    {
      Session* session;
      Status status = NewSession(SessionOptions(), &session);

```
  const std::string graph_fn = "/tensorflowtest/model-0617/model.meta";
  MetaGraphDef graphdef;
  Status status_load = ReadBinaryProto(Env::Default(), graph_fn, &graphdef); 
  if (!status_load.ok()) {
        return -1;
  }
Status status_create = session->Create(graphdef.graph_def()); 
if (!status_create.ok()) {
   std::cout << "ERROR: Creating graph in session failed..." << status_create.ToString() << std::endl;
        return -1;
  }
  cout << "Session successfully created.Load model successfully!"<< endl;


  const std::string checkpointPath = "/media/root/Ubuntu311/projects/Ecology_projects/tensorflowtest/model-0617/model";
  Tensor checkpointPathTensor(DT_STRING, TensorShape());
  checkpointPathTensor.scalar<std::string>()() = checkpointPath;
  status = session->Run(
      {{ graphdef.saver_def().filename_tensor_name(), checkpointPathTensor },},
      {},{graphdef.saver_def().restore_op_name()},nullptr);
  if (!status.ok())
  {
      throw runtime_error("Error loading checkpoint from " + checkpointPath + ": " + status.ToString());
  }
  cout << "Load weights successfully!"<< endl;


  //read image for prediction...
  string image_path= "/media/root/Ubuntu311/projects/Ecology_projects/copy/cnn-imgs/AABW.jpg";
   int input_height =48;
   int input_width=160;
   int input_mean=0;
   int input_std=1;
   std::vector<Tensor> resized_tensors;
   Status read_tensor_status =
   ReadImageFile(image_path, input_height, input_width, input_mean,
                           input_std, &resized_tensors);
   if (!read_tensor_status.ok()) {
     LOG(ERROR) << read_tensor_status;
     cout<<"resing error"<<endl;
     return -1;
   }

   const Tensor& resized_tensor = resized_tensors[0];
   std::cout <<"Read image successfully: "<< resized_tensor.DebugString()<<endl;
   //I do not know if it is wrong that making "input" and "is_training" together to the variable--resized_tensor.
   std::string Input1Name = "input";
   std::string Input2Name = "is_training";
   vector<std::pair<string, Tensor> > inputs;
   inputs.push_back(std::make_pair(Input1Name, resized_tensor));
   inputs.push_back(std::make_pair(Input2Name, resized_tensor));

   vector<tensorflow::Tensor> outputs;
   //I do not know if i should make "out_softmax" or "output" as the 2nd argument in session->Run and the 3rd should be null or not.
   string output2="out_softmax";
   string output_ = "output";
   //session->Run returns the error information--"model_pruner failed: Invalid argument: Invalid input graph." 
   Status status_run = session->Run(inputs, {output2}, {}, &outputs);
   if (!status_run.ok()) {
       std::cout << "ERROR: RUN failed..."  << std::endl;
       std::cout << status_run.ToString() << "\n";
       return -1;
   }
   ...
}
```

The information below is the whole prints:

```
Session successfully created.Load model successfully!
Load weights successfully!
Read image successfully: Tensor<type: float shape: [1,48,160,1] values: [[[0.592156887][0.603921592][0.603921592]]]...>
2019-07-03 14:47:02.087086: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:486] model_pruner failed: Invalid argument: Invalid input graph.
```

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, please extract a [mcve] from your code instead. This means removing anything that is not called (e.g. code after the error), but keep everything that is needed (like e.g. the model file). The goal is that everyone here can test your code to reproduce the problem. BTW: Make sure that you throw the error message and a few keywords as context at a search engine, maybe others have had similar problems.

Comment: Thank you ! I am a new user here and i am reading what you recommand to me. I think i will edit my question later.

Comment: You pass the same tensor as value for `input` and `is_training`, but shouldn't `is_training` be a scalar bool tensor instead? (like `Tensor is_traning_val(DT_BOOL, TensorShape()); is_traning_val.scalar<bool>()() = false;`) About names, I _think_ for ops with one output (most of them), you can give either `output` or `output:0` to `Run` and you get the value of that single output. Similarly, for inputs I think you can use either `input` or `input:0` if it's not ambiguous. The third parameter is just for ops you want to run but don't need the value (e.g. a var assign), I don't think you need it.

Comment: Thank you very much,i will give it a try right now.